# Traefik Service Fabric backend not populating

Tags: azure-service-fabric, traefik

I have a guest executable service deployed to Service Fabric with the following Traefik tags:

```
<StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="MyServiceServiceType" UseImplicitHost="true">
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Name="Traefik">
          <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule">PathPrefixStrip:/myservice</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.expose">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.passHostHeader">true</Label>
          </Labels>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </StatelessServiceType>
```

And the Traefik toml file is configured with the ServiceFabric backend as follows:

```
[serviceFabric]
clusterManagementUrl = "http://localhost:19080"
apiVersion = "3.0"
refreshSeconds = 10
```

However when i navigate to the traefik UI the service is displaying on the left hand side under the 'ServiceFabric' tab but the endpoints on the right hand side show no items in the table.

Is there something missing in order to get them to be displayed.

Comment: Looks like the SF support on Traefik is still in preview, there is not much documentation about it, just a few in their github repository, you should check it there to find some answers

Comment: This is a long time ago, but my answer may help.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132155/which-matcher-should-i-use-for-a-service-hosted-on-localhost-port-for-a-local/52140875#52140875